# Windows Store Application Session

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am developing windows store application. I need to create sessions for the app in c#.
how to do this in windows store applications?

Comment: Once you cross 15 points, You can upvote, the answers you accepted :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article will best help you manage sessions

[Manage app lifecycle and state (Windows Store apps using C#/VB and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx)

Its is part 2 of a series. It might be worthwhile to go through the entire series