# Associate Windows Store App to Session

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-server

I have a Windows Desktop App(written in c#) that knows all Windows session information about all sessions and I have Windows Store App(written in c#) that needs to know itself Windows session information.
How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Store Application Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121039/windows-store-application-session)

Comment: Writing "session information" I'm talking about "Windows session information", not "Windows Store App session"

Comment: You may want to clear that up then. You said "needs to know itself session information".

Comment: OK! Sorry for my bad english... is it correct now?

Comment: So, Windows Store apps don't get much access to system information. You'll have to describe what system information you are looking for for us to help you. In general though, no you can't do that.

Comment: Yes! but my Windows App Desktop(or WCF Localhost) know all information that i want (ex. ip client or session id..) i must associate Windows App Store with one of my session.

Comment: The Windows Store app can communicate with WCF, you can create a file which both of them share, or you can use one as a server and the other as a client.

Comment: OK, but my WCF know all session information but it don't know which specific session the Store App is located. (is possible get Login Time ?...  or for example Environment.TickCount is different in the several sessions in Windows Server 2012?) ..Sorry for my bad english..